# Android TableLayout: span 2 TextViews on 4 cells

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

Android application layout.xml contains 3 three rows. The 1-st and the 2-nd rows (each) are of 4 cells, 3-rd one is of 2 cells (`TextViews`'s). The aim is to span 2 `TextViews`'s on the 3-rd row on the whole row. These 2 `TextViews`'s is of different lengths, so  `layout_span` (spanning each of 2 elements on 2 cell) doesn't produces desired effect. Some improvement is achieved by `weight`'s, but the spanned 3-rd row takes some effect on the 1-st and 2-nd rows.

I solve this problem by wrapping the 3-rd row with inner `TableLayout` (it is instead of the 3-rd `TableRow`):

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunrizeLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@id/sunrizeValue"
            android:text="@string/sunrize_string" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sunrizeValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/middayLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@id/middayValue"
            android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
            android:text="@string/midday" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/middayValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sunsetLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@id/sunsetValue"
            android:text="@string/sunset_string" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sunsetValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/midnightLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:labelFor="@id/midnightValue"
            android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
            android:text="@string/midnight" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/midnightValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daylightLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:labelFor="@id/daylightValue"
                android:text="@string/daylight" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/daylightValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:enabled="false"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="time"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</TableLayout>
```

However, some unpleasant message appears: `TableRow` in the inner `TableLayout` is considered as useless, and I'm advised to remove on of them. Logic of such behaviour is clear, but in this case  both `TableLayout` and its `TableRow` are needed. So, the question is: is there way to avoid this message, without suppressing?